# How to modify temporary files when running apptainer interactivelly

Tags: docker, singularity-container, apptainer

When running my container with docker I need to modify one file

```
sed -i  "242s/.decode('utf-8')//" /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py
```

When running the .sif file I have created from the docker image (I need this to run it on a different server).

To build the sif, I did this  `singularity build local_tar.sif docker-archive://local.tar`

When my sif file, the same command to modify the file doesn't work

```
sed -i  "242s/.decode('utf-8')//" /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py
sed: couldn't open temporary file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/sedSoXiZF: Read-only file system
```

Reading the documentation I have seen the parameter `--writable-tmpfs`   but I got the following error

```
Apptainer> sed -i  "242s/.decode('utf-8')//" /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py
sed: couldn't open temporary file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/sedKvfuLn: No data available
```